# Laravel Homestead - nothing running on port 80

Tags: laravel, homestead

I've managed to get the Laraval Homestead vagrant VM up and running, and I can ssh into the VM with `vagrant ssh`, and I can also ping the IP address that is set for the machine which is 192.168.10.10, and it responds fine.

When I do an `nmap 192.168.10.10` from WSL, I don't see anything is running on port 80. Shouldn't Homestead have an already running and configured HTTP server running?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and add in hosts file the IP 192.168.10.10 with the name of your site. For example: 192.168.10.10   mylaravelapp.test